# Run-time error '424' when trying to MsgBox cell reference address

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to return the cell reference address as a string.

```
1   Sub Test()
2       minLoc = Worksheets("Skills").Range("C2")
3       Dim Loc As String
4       Loc = minLoc.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
5       MsgBox (Loc)
6   End Sub
```

The error, "Run-time error '424':," occurs at line 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change minLoc to a range and set it.  As you have it written, VBA is using it as a string.  The string will have no .Address property.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim minLoc As Range
    Set minLoc = Worksheets("Skills").Range("C2")
    Dim Loc As String
    Loc = minLoc.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    MsgBox (Loc)
End Sub
```

Comment: When I use that, It returns the cell value and not the cell address

Comment: Wait MsgBox should contain Loc not minLoc

Comment: I made the change to your question and reflected it in the answer.